# Ruby tracking self inside Array#each

Tags: ruby, self

I'm having a little trouble tracking self in the following example:

```
# a simple class
class Foo; end

# open the Class class to add an instance method 
class Class
  # breakpoint 1 - self is equal to Class right here, I get why
  puts self

  # usage: Foo.some_method(1,2,3)
  def some_method(*args)
    # breakpoint 2 - when we call Foo.some_method(*args) 
    # self is equal to Foo, and once again I understand why
    puts self

    args.each do |arg|
      # breakpoint 3 - self is still equal to Foo, even though we are calling each
      # on an explicit receiver (an array called args) 
      puts self
    end
  end
end
```

So how come **self** does not change when I call `each` on the args array ? I was under the impression that self is always equal to the receiver, which would be the array surely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self` is always equal to the receiver *in the method itself*. A block you pass to each is a closure on the scope in which it is defined, where `self` is equal to a `Foo`.

---

This makes perfect sense when you think about it. In C++, should a `for` loop change `this`? Blocks are made to allow you to pass your code that executes in *your environment* to other code so that methods can replace language constructs like `for`, or some language's `using`, and so on.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense, lexical scoping init? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, almost anything is *possible* even if it is not *advisable*.

So as you noted, simply calling `self` in a normal `each` block will return the lexical scope, ie. in the REPL, `main`:

```
[1,2,3].each {|e| p "#{self} - #{e}" }
# "main - 1"
# "main - 2"
# "main - 3"
# => [1, 2, 3]
```

But, we can get the scope we want, which is the instance of the receiver of `each` by using [instance_eval](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval):

```
[1,2,3].instance_eval { each {|e| p "#{self} - #{e}" } }
"[1, 2, 3] - 1"
"[1, 2, 3] - 2"
"[1, 2, 3] - 3"
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

*Periculo tuo ingredere!*

Addendum:

I did a benchmark just out of curiosity, expecting a big performance penalty from `instance_eval`:

```
require 'benchmark'

a = Array.new(1_000_000, 1)

Benchmark.bmbm(100) do |x|
  x.report("inline, self=main") { a.each {|e| self && e } }
  x.report("assigned") { a.each {|e| a && e } }
  x.report("inline, instance_eval") { a.instance_eval { each {|e| self && e } } }
end
```

These were the results:

```
Rehearsal ---------------------------------------------------------
inline, self=main       0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.037743)
assigned                0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.043800)
inline, instance_eval   0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.041955)
------------------------------------------------ total: 0.120000sec

                            user     system      total        real
inline, self=main       0.030000   0.000000   0.030000 (  0.038312)
assigned                0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.043693)
inline, instance_eval   0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.040029)
```